# C# сервис принимающий json запросы

Tags: c#, json, вконтакте, callback

Господа разработчики!
Подскажите, каким "инструментарием" воспользоваться, чтобы создать сервис, принимающий json запросы и отправляющий ответы. Вариант c node.js я знаю. Однако, хотел бы обойтись только платформой .net. Мне не нужно кусков кода готового, просто укажите направление.
Запросы, в частности, будут приходить с VK Api Callback.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите иметь достаточно полный контроль над обработкой запросов, я бы порекомендовал отложить модные `WCF`, `ASP.NET Web API` и уж тем более `ASP.NET MVC`. Начните со старой, доброй, простогй и надёжной модели `HttpModule` + `HttpHandler`. Ничего лишнего, максимальная прозрачность и атомарность.

1. [Общие сведения об обработчиках HTTP-данных и HTTP-модулях](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb398986.aspx)
2. [Пошаговое руководство: создание синхронного обработчика HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228090(v=vs.100).aspx)
3. [Пошаговое руководство. Создание и регистрация пользовательского HTTP-модуля](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx)

Всё, что вам надо, для того, чтобы начать обрабатывать запросы, причём не только json, а любые:

Создайте сборку:

```
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public HelloWorldHandler()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        Response.Write("Hello from a synchronous custom HTTP handler.");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

И пропищите рядом с ней в `<assemblyName>.web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.sample" 
        type="HelloWorldHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Всё. Можно размещать эту пару файлов в папку сайта на IIS и обрабатывать любые запросы. Когда вы освоитесь с этим и будет чёткое понимание того, как работает IIS, можно развлекаться с более продвинутыми технологиями.

Answer (score 2):

1. WCF
2. ASP.NET Web Services (устарел)
3. ASP.NET MVC
4. ASP.NET Web Api

Для "чистой" работы с JSON лучше всего подходит последний вариант. WCF следует использовать если вы помимо json-api хотите предоставить еще и soap-api. MVC надо использовать если вам помимо api нужен еще и веб-сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/)

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Post["/callback"] = (_, ctx) =>
        {
            var requestBody = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(request);

            //Обработка запроса

            return Task.FromResult<dynamic>(requestBody.type == "confirmation" ? Response.AsText("701ab1ef") : Response.AsText("ok"));
        };
    }
}
```